# Why do we Compare Correlation Coefficient?

Tags: regression, correlation, anova, regression-coefficients

In the study I am conducting, (Group A) the correlation coefficient between black & white imagery and retention is given by R1 and is significant. And (Group B) the correlation coefficient between colorful imagery and retention is given by R2 and is significant.

When I compare R1 and R2, I get R2>R1. Using the Fisher Z-Transform, I found that Zobs did not fall within the range  -1.96 < Zobs < 1.96, and therefore they are not statistically significant.

Can we deduce retention was equivalent for both groups A and B. I am not sure how to best interpret this analysis. Kindly advise.

[image: Fisher Z-Transform]

Comment: What is Zobs..?

Comment: When it does not fall within that range, it means it *is* statistically significant.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.What does that imply if the difference of two correlation coefficients is significant to our results? What information does it provide?  Can I deduce that strength between colorful imagery- retention and between B/W - retention in the sample  was not  equivalent (since I  reject the null hypothesis)

Comment: It has the same meaning as for any statistical significance test. What is your specific doubt here?

Comment: Can I deduce that strength between colorful imagery- retention and between B/W - retention in the sample was not equivalent (since I reject the null hypothesis). Also probably I am not clear why do we need to compare the correlations of two different populations? What additional info do we gain? Thanks in advance, looking forward for an elaboration so that I can apply the same into my own research paper.

Comment: I did not receive any clear answer to my question. For instance, when the difference of the coefficient correlation between Group A and Group B is not statistically significant, what does that imply?